# How to pass previous form data to the constructor of a DynamicForm in FormWizard

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I have a FormWizard where I need data from the first form to pass to the constructor of the second form so I can build a dynamic form.

I can get the first form's data via the process_step of the FormWizard.

I create the fields of the second form with a database call of the list of fields.

```
class ConditionWizardDynamicQuestions(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, DynamicQuestions=None, *args, **kwargs):
       super(ConditionWizardDynamicQuestions, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       questions = Question.objects.filter(MYDATA = DATA_FROM_1STFORM)
       for q in questions:
            dynField = FieldFactory(q)
            self.fields[q.label] = dynField
```

How can I pass over the **DATA_FROM_1STFORM** ?

---

my resultant code:
I abandoned the **init** of the form, and switched it to the CreateQuestions def.  Then used the wizard's get_form override to alter the form after creation.

```
class ConditionWizard(SessionFormWizard):
    def get_form(self, request, storage, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(ConditionWizard, self).get_form(request, storage, step, data, files)
        stepIndex = self.get_step_index(request, storage, step)
        if stepIndex == 1:
            form.CreateQuestions(request.session["WizardConditionId"])
        if stepIndex == 3:
            form.fields['hiddenConditionId'].initial = request.session["WizardConditionId"]
            form.fields['medicationName'].queryset = Medication.objects.filter(condition = request.session["WizardConditionId"])
        return form
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FormWizard already passes the data from each previous form to the next form. If you want to get that data in order to instantiate a class (for example, if a form has special keyword arguments that it requires), one way of doing it is to grab the querydict by overriding `get_form` in your form wizard class. For example:

```
class SomeFormWizard(FormWizard):
    def get_form(self, step, data=None):
        if step == 1 and data: # change this to whatever step requires
                               # the extra data
            extra_data = data.get('key_from_querydict')
            if extra_data:
                return self.form_list[step](data,
                                            keyword_argument=extra_data,
                                            prefix=self.prefix_for_step(step),                                                                                                                                            
                                            initial=self.initial.get(step, None))
        # Fallback for the other forms.
        return self.form_list[step](data,
                                    prefix=self.prefix_for_step(step),                                                                                                                                            
                                    initial=self.initial.get(step, None))
```

Note that you can also override `parse_params(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` in FormWizard to access the url/request data, just like you would in a view, so if you have request data (`request.user`, for instance) that is going to be needed for all of the forms, it might be better to get the data from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm running into a problem passing data from step 1 to step 3, but your solution is helpful and insightful.

Comment: What sort of problem are you running into? AFAIK it should let you access all of the data from all of the previous forms - that is, step 3 should have the data from step 1 and step 2.

Comment: my problem was I was attempting to use initial from the wizard and overriding the form's __init__.   I switched to using the get_form and the world is getting clearer for me :)

Answer (score 8):

I solved this by overriding get_form_kwargs for the WizardView. It normally just returns an empty dictionary that get_form populates, so by overriding it to return a dictionary with the data you need prepopulated, you can pass kwargs to your form init.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
    kwargs = {}
    if step == '1':
        your_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')['your_data']
        kwargs.update({'your_data': your_data,})
    return kwargs
```

Then, in your form **init** method you can just pop the kwarg off before calling super:

```
self.your_data = kwargs.pop('client', None)
```

Answer (score 3):

Override the get_form_kwargs method of your form wizard in views

view.py

```
class FormWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
        kwargs = {}
        if step == '1':
            step0_form_field = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')['previous_form_field_data']
            kwargs.update({'step0_form_field': step0_form_field})
        return kwargs
```

Override the init of your form by popping up the data you got from the previous field to create a dynamic field.

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    #some fields

class MyForm1(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        extra = kwargs.pop('step0_form_field')
        super(MyForm1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(extra):
            self.fields['name_%s' % i] = forms.CharField()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was recently working with django form wizard, and i was solving the similar issue. I don't think you can pass data to **init**, however, what you can do, is override the **init** constructor:

```
next_form = self.form_list[1]

# let's change the __init__
# function which will set the choices :P
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    super(next_form, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
    self.fields['availability'].choices = ...
next_form.__init__ = __init__
```

It's quite annoying that in python you can't declare and assign a function in one go and have to put it in the namespace (unless you use lambdas), but oh well.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.   Is this code overriding the __init__ of the subclassed FormWizard?  How does this allow me to get the data from step1 to step2?

Comment: no, it overrides the __init__ of the next form. Notice how it says self.fields['availability'].choices = ..., now instead of ... you can put any data you want to pass

Comment: I already have the "next_form" __init__ overrided, so I still don't see how your passing data from the previous form of the wizard.

Comment: Oh, this code has to be inside process_step method of wizard - that way you can get self.form_list[0].cleaned_data, and base the new __init__ on that