# Django FormWizard - How do you dynamically create a formset based on previous step

Tags: django, formwizard, django-forms, django-formwizard

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940138/how-to-pass-previous-form-data-to-the-constructor-of-a-dynamicform-in-formwizard) post and it's not working (in part because it's dated).  I've also studied the source tree to no avail (the tests helped) but I can't find my answer. What I'm looking to do is get a seed set of data in form0 ('start') which will dynamically build a formset for step2.  Step 2 is simply a verification step.

1. 'start' - User enters subdivision (subA), zipcode (12345) and a csv of lots (51,52,53)
2. 'step2' - A dynamic form (modelformset) is created with 3 forms representing 51,52,53
3. User hits go and the models are built

i.e.

```
data = [ { 'subdivision': <subA>, 'zipcode': '12345', 'lot_number': '51'}
         { 'subdivision': <subA>, 'zipcode': '12345', 'lot_number': '52'}
         { 'subdivision': <subA>, 'zipcode': '12345', 'lot_number': '53'} ]
```

**What I've tried**

When implementing the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940138/how-to-pass-previous-form-data-to-the-constructor-of-a-dynamicform-in-formwizard) I only get `data=None`.  This is dated and looking through the source I thought the "right" way to do this was to simply override the `get_form_instance` method and feed it`get_cleaned_data_for_step`,  but that appears to revalidate and do *a lot* more stuff than what I think it needs to (and it didn't work).

So.. What I'm looking for is two things.

1. What is the right way to get the previous forms data.
2. How do I take that data and use it to create a n-number of formsets.

FWIW I am using Django 1.4-alpha formset wizard.

Here is what I have.

```
# urls.py
    url(r'homes/bulk/$', TestWizard.as_view([('start', BulkHomeForm0),
                                             ('step2', HomeFormSet)])),

# Models.py
class Subdivision(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Home(models.Model):
    lot_number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    subdivision = models.ForeignKey(Subdivision)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_zipcode], null=True)

# Forms
class BulkHomeForm0(forms.Form):
    subdivision = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subdivision.objects.all(), required=True)
    zipcode = USZipCodeField(required=True)
    lots = forms.CharField(max_length=5000, widget=forms.Textarea()

    def clean(self):
        subdivision = self.cleaned_data.get('subdivision', False)
        zipcode = self.cleaned_data.get('zipcode', False)
        final_data = []
        for item in self.cleaned_data.get('lots', "").split(",")
            final_data.append({'subdivision':subdivision, 
                               'zipcode':zipcode, 
                               'lot_number':item})
        self.cleaned_data['homes'] = final_data

class BulkHomeForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Home

HomeFormSet = modelformset_factory(Home, form=BulkHomeForm1, extra=2)

# Views.py
class TestWizard(WizardView):
    storage_name = 'django.contrib.formtools.wizard.storage.session.SessionStorage'

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(TestWizard, self).get_form(step=step, data=data, files=files)
        return form

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return render_to_response('done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I came up with..

I couldn't seem to get a modelForm to work nicely so I kept the two separate and merged them at `done`.  It isn't perfect yet but it's getting close..

```
class BulkHomeForm1(forms.Form):

    lot_number = forms.CharField(max_length=16, required=True)
    street_line1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    floorplan = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Floorplan.objects.filter(is_active=True), required=False)
    start_date = forms.DateField(required=False)

temp_storage_location = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, prefix="bulk_homes_")
os.chmod(temp_storage_location,  02775) # TODO FIX ME
temp_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=temp_storage_location)

class BulkHomeWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = temp_storage

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):

        form = super(BulkHomeWizard, self).get_form(step=step, data=data, files=files)
        if self.steps.current == 'start' and form.prefix != "step2":
            # Limit the subdivisions down to the specifics
            sub_qs = Subdivision.objects.filter(is_active=True)
            if self.request.user.company_type == "rater":
                sub_qs = sub_qs.filter(rater_orgs=self.request.user.company.id)
            elif self.request.user.company_type == "eep":
                sub_qs = sub_qs.filter(eep_orgs=self.request.user.company.id)
            form.fields['subdivision'].queryset = sub_qs
        return form

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(BulkHomeWizard, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)
        self.template_name = 'axis/bulk_%s.html' %  self.steps.current
        return context

    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        """This is used to seed the model set with information from the previous step"""
        if step == 'step2':
            log.info("Into Step 2")
            data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('start')['homes']
            return data
        return self.initial_dict.get(step, {})

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

        cleaned_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

        subdivision = cleaned_data[0].get('subdivision')
        city = subdivision.city
        state = subdivision.state
        zipcode = cleaned_data[0].get('zipcode')

        for form in cleaned_data[1]:
            data = Home.objects.get_or_create(lot_number = form.get('lot_number'),
                                              floorplan = form.get('floorplan', None),
                                              street_line1 = form.get('street_line1', None),
                                              subdivision = subdivision,
                                              city = subdivision.city, state=subdivision.state,
                                              zipcode=zipcode,
                                              start_date = form.get('start_date', None),)
            obj, created = data
            obj.clean()
            obj.save()
            if created:
                log.info("Create new Home")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("subdivision_view", kwargs={'subdivision_id': subdivision.id}))
```